# Windows 11 intermittent touchpad issue

Tags: windows, laptop, touchpad, windows-11, dell-xps

I've had an intermittent problem with my laptop touchpad

It doesn't stop working completely, but after my laptop has been on and running for an hour or so this problem starts. When I first touch the pad the mouse cursor won't move for a couple of seconds. I have to keep my finger on the pad for about 2 seconds, and then the cursor moves. After I restart the problem goes away and cycle starts again, similarly if I log out and back in again it can solve the issue temporarily.

Pad clicks work fine, as does the touchscreen, but scrolling with two fingers does not.

I have reinstalled the driver. I've also tried using procexp to search for 'hook.dll' in case I could spot a program using it.

Recent changes are installing Windows 11 (in October, about a week before this started), and uninstalling Touchpad Blocker (a couple of days after this started to see if it was the problem).

Laptop is a Dell XPS 15 7590 purchased in June last year.

Can anyone suggest anything else I can try to diagnose this?

Comment: Have you tried adjusting touchpad sensitivity and setting for ignoring palm-touch (i.e., large area, rather than finger)? https://www.digitalcitizen.life/touchpad-settings-windows-11/ Since this happens only after some time, it might be a gradual warming or dampening that causes the issue, rather than the OS alone.

Comment: @DrMoishePippik yes I've tried adjusting those settings to no avail. I'm convinced this isn't a hardware issue as logging out and in again fixes it (temporarily).

Comment: I have exactly the same problem on the same laptop (XPS 15 7590), but on Windows 10. There is [another question for the same issue here](https://superuser.com/questions/1736111). Did you find any solution?

Comment: @Qtax No, but it did mostly stop happening on its own eventually. I did find that if I used a new user account it wouldn't happen at all, which led me to believe it was something I had installed on my account rather than a hardware issue, and therefore I was considering a fresh Windows install. Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

> I've had an intermittent problem with my laptop touchpad ..... Laptop
> is a Dell XPS 15 7590 purchased in June last year.
>
> Can anyone suggest anything else I can try to diagnose this?

If the newest driver does not fix the issue, you need to contact Dell Support about the issue.

The machine should still be under warranty (9 months old).

There may be a compatibility issue with Windows 11 - should not be but this is also a question for Dell.