# Why does my touchpad sometimes not work unless I hold my finger on it for a few seconds?

Tags: windows-10, drivers, touchpad

My ThinkPad X1 Carbon (7th generation) sometimes has the same problem as [this person on Microsoft Answers](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/all/touchpad-cannot-move-the-pointer-after-few-seconds/be602994-b685-4c36-b3d0-1073c607976b). Sometimes, after I've been using the computer for a while, the touchpad becomes unresponsive. The cursor won't move immediately when I move my finger on the touchpad. If I keep moving my finger, after a few seconds it will start working normally. Clicking the touchpad will also restore the normal behaviour as long as my finger stays on the touchpad. As soon as I lift my finger off, it will revert to the broken state, and if I put my finger down again it will take a few seconds of continuous input to respond.

Rebooting typically fixes this. The Microsoft Answers post suggests updating the touchpad drivers, but when I open the touchpad in Device Manager, it's using a generic Microsoft driver for which there is no update:

[image: Screenshot of Device Manager dialog for HID-compliant touchpad]

I've discovered that I can also fix the problem by disabling and re-enabling the device from this dialog without a full reboot, so I'm pretty sure it is a driver or firmware bug of some kind. But the Lenovo website doesn't have a touchpad driver for this laptop, and I don't seem to have the UltraNav or PalmCheck settings under Mouse Properties as described in [this blog post](http://www.hanselman.com/blog/fix-external-mouse-freezing-on-lenovo-laptops-with-synaptics-touchpad). I'm also skeptical that the problem has something to do with PalmCheck, as suggested in [this Reddit thread from someone who seems to have had the same issue on two different ThinkPads](https://old.reddit.com/r/thinkpad/comments/39z9rf/trackpad_randomly_cuts_out_for_a_few_seconds_on/).

I did find some [updated firmware](https://download.lenovo.com/pccbbs/mobiles/n2hgc06w.txt) for the touchpad, but I apparently already had that installed.

Comment: I'm wondering if the device for some reason became subject to power savings and sent to standby mode.

Comment: Run the Lenovo driver update app and see if it finds a newer Synaptics or Elan driver (whichever you have).

Comment: Exactly same problem with my Dell XPS 15 7590. Seems to start happening in relation to sleep/hibernation, but that's just speculation. [Another question for the same issue](https://superuser.com/questions/1707957) on Windows 11.